# Ignore definitions in one project but not the other

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a workspace with a `node_modules` folder and a `src` folder that has my **client** and **server** typescript code. It looks like this:

```
/node_modules
  /@types
    /node
    /requirejs
/src
  /client
    /admin
      /index.ts
      /tsconfig.json
    /public
      /index.ts
      /tsconfig.json
  /server
    /index.ts
    /tsconfig.json
```

I am using `requirejs` for my **client** code, and `node` for my **server** code. Each of them have similar typings, so when I build my code, I get the following errors:

```
node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(6860,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'mod'.
node_modules/@types/requirejs/index.d.ts(38,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'mod'.
node_modules/@types/requirejs/index.d.ts(422,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.
```

Is there a way for my **client** code to ignore the `node` definitions, and my **server** code to ignore the `requirejs` definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have separate `tsconfig.json` files for the client and server builds, you'll just need to set the [`types` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) to limit the `node_modules/@types` packages that are automatically loaded in each build.  Alternatively, you could set up separate `node_modules` directories for the two builds.  If you have trouble getting this to work, add more information to your question and I will look again.

Comment: the `types` option seems to help.

Comment: I am aslo haveing same problem but this does not solve my problem